# How Do I add the distinct statement to my query?

Tags: query, distinct

This is my code:

```
$statusTable = $dbHelper->getTableName("mp_os_statuses");

        $this
            ->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(array('status'=>$statusTable), "status.value = main_table.status")
            ->order("status.position ASC")
            ;
```

I actived the sql logs I executed the latest query and I saw that I have 2 **entity_id**s with the same value. As a result I get the error message:

```
 with the same id "27" already exist
```

So I search over the internet that I should add a distinct statement to my query. How can I do that ? thx

**UPDATE**  This is the query from the log:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `status`.* FROM `mp_os_state_status` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `mp_os_statuses` AS `status` ON status.value = main_table.status WHERE (main_table.state = 'payment_review') ORDER BY `status`.`position` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should added the **group by** condition, not **distinct**:

```
        $this
            ->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(array('status'=>$statusTable), "status.value = main_table.status")
            ->group('entity_id')
            ->order("status.position ASC")
            ;
```